# How to avoid coding if statement twice

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, logical-operators, code-duplication

I program mostly by myself so nobody checks my code. I feel like I've developed a bunch of bad habits.

The code I am pasting here works, but I would like to hear some other solutions.

I create a dictionary called `teams_shots`. I iterate through a pandas dataframe, which has the name of the away team and the home team in one row. I would like to keep track of shots made by each team that appears in the data frame. That is why I check if `home_team_name` or `away_team_name` do not have an entry in the dictionary, if so I create one.

```
for index,match in df.iterrows():
    if match['home_team_name'] not in teams_shots:
        #we have to setup an entry in the dictionary
        teams_shots[match['home_team_name']]=[]
        teams_shots[match['home_team_name']].append(match['home_team_shots'])
        home_shots_avg.append(None)
    else:
        home_shots_avg.append(np.mean(teams_shots[match['home_team_name']]))
        teams_shots[match['home_team_name']].append(match['home_team_shots'])

    if match['away_team_name'] not in teams_shots:
        teams_shots[match['away_team_name']]=[]
        teams_shots[match['away_team_name']].append(match['away_team_shots'])
        away_shots_avg.append(None)
    else:
        away_shots_avg.append(np.mean(teams_shots[match['away_team_name']])) 
        teams_shots[match['away_team_name']].append(match['away_team_shots'])
```

As you can see almost the same code is written twice, which is not a sign of good programming. I thought about using an `or` operator in the if statement, but then one entry might already be made and I would truncate it. Any ideas how to write this code better.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I feel that it would be better suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: What does your input dataframe, df look like? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think an additional `for` loop should do the trick:

```
for index,match in df.iterrows():
        for name, shots in {'home_team_name':'home_team_shots',
                            'away_team_name':'away_team_shots'}:

            if match[name] not in teams_shots:
                #we have to setup an entry in the dictionary
                teams_shots[name]=[]
                teams_shots[name].append(match[shots])
                home_shots_avg.append(None)
             else:
                home_shots_avg.append(np.mean(teams_shots[name]))
```

But there might be a way to handle this in a vectorized fashion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. home_shots_avg still need to be taken care of though. I made a dictionary home_away_avg={'home_team_'+attr: [],'away_team_'+attr: []}

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `get` as a quick lookup. It doesn't throw `KeyErrors` and the default `None` acts as `False` in truthiness

```
for index, match in df.iterrows():
    home, away, home_shots, away_shots = match['home_team_name'],
                           match['away_team_name'],
                           match['home_team_shots'],
                           match['away_team_shots']


    if not teams_shots.get(home):
        # No need to separately allocate the array
        teams_shots[home] = [home]
        home_shots_avg.append(None)
    else:
        home_shots_avg.append(np.mean(teams_shots[home_shots]))

    if not teams_shots.get(away):
        teams_shots[away] = [away]
        away_shots_avg.append(None)
    else:
        away_shots_avg.append(np.mean(teams_shots[away_shots]))
```